# Tabview cannot update selection when selection is optional?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-tabview

I have the following code snippet. The 'selectedTab' in 'FirstTabView' updates automatically when I swipe between tabs. But if I change 'selectedTab' to be an optional value as shown in 'SecondTabView', then the 'selectedTab' does not update and always show 2. Could someone help explain it?

```
struct FirstTabView: View {
    @State private var selectedTab: Int = 2

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
                Text("Tab 1")
                    .tag(1)
                Text("Tab 2")
                    .tag(2)
                Text("Tab 3")
                    .tag(3)
            }
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
            Text(String(selectedTab))
        }
    }
}

struct SecondTabView: View {
    @State private var selectedTab: Int?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
                Text("Tab 1")
                    .tag(1)
                Text("Tab 2")
                    .tag(2)
                Text("Tab 3")
                    .tag(3)
            }
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
            Text(String(selectedTab ?? 2))
        }
    }
}
```

I create a new non-optional variable to bind the selection and then the 'selectedTab' can update automatically again. But I checked the SwiftUI Documentation and the tabview does accept an optional value as selection parameter.

```
struct SecondTabView: View {
    @State private var selectedTab: Int?
    
    var tabBinding: Binding<Int> {
        Binding(
            get: { selectedTab ?? 2 },
            set: { selectedTab = $0 }
        )
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TabView(selection: $tabBinding) {
                Text("Tab 1")
                    .tag(1)
                Text("Tab 2")
                    .tag(2)
                Text("Tab 3")
                    .tag(3)
            }
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
            Text(String(selectedTab ?? 2))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want an optional tab selection value? Which tab do you want to be selected when it is nil? Also, there is no `TabView` initialiser that specifically takes in `Binding<T?>` - there is only one that takes in `Binding<T>?`, which is not the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The type of the selection must exactly match the type of the `tag`s you give to the tabs.

You are giving `Int` tags to the tabs, but the selection's type is `Int?`, so the selection value is not updated. There is no `Int?` value SwiftUI can set, such that it is equal to (by using the `==` operator required by `Equatable`) the non-nullable `Int` "1". After all, `Equatable` can only compare things of the same type.

Note that although you can normally compare `Int` and `Int?` because as a language feature, you are allowed to write the non-optional value where an optional is expected. The internals of SwiftUI doesn't have this "feature".

If you want to use an optional type as the selection value, make the tags optional too:

```
Text("Tab 1")
    .tag(1 as Int?) // also can be written as Optional.some(1)
Text("Tab 2")
    .tag(2 as Int?)
Text("Tab 3")
    .tag(3 as Int?)
```

That said, the initial value of `selectedTab` would be `nil`, and there is no tabs with the tag `nil`, so (at least in my testing) the first tab is initially selected (but does not change the selection value to 1).

So I'm not sure why you would use an optional selection value in this case. In fact, I can't think of any case where it would be *useful*. If you want to have a "default" tab, just initialise `selectedTab` to one of the tags.

> But I checked the SwiftUI Documentation and the tabview does accept an optional value as selection parameter.

You have probably found [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/tabview/init(selection:content:)):

```
init(
    selection: Binding<SelectionValue>?,
    @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content
)
```

`Binding<SelectionValue>?` is not a binding of an optional value, which would be written `Binding<SelectionValue?>`. It is a binding that is optional, i.e. it allows you to write:

```
TabView(selection: nil) { ... }
```

So when you pass your `$selectedTab`, which is a `Binding<Int?>`, the tab view's `SelectionValue` is `Int?`, and it looks for tags of type `Int?`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. You are absolutely right, Binding<SelectionValue>? is not a binding of an optional value. I do not know why I thought it was. I have a sidebar view to display a list of items, and a view to display the selected item. I want to add a swipe gesture to easily switch between items. I initially added a swipe gesture to implement it. Then I thought that the page style tabview also has similar feature, so I tried to use tabview to see if it could be achieved. The reason I want to use a binding of an optional value is that a user may delete all items.